# Select the nth following sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wondered if there is a better solution than to what I found without changing the html-structure

The HTML structure looks like this

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

So there's various DIVs on the same level, what I want to do is to color every fourth block differently, until a divider appears, then it'd have to recount.

I thought something like `.block:nth-child(4n)` would do the trick, but it actually counts the elements based on the parent, not based on the class.

Here's the JSFiddle to try out.
Block #4 and #8 in each row should be differently colored
http://jsfiddle.net/SKgdH/3/

And this is how I made it sort-of work:
http://jsfiddle.net/SKgdH/1/

What I did was to look for the 4th sibling of the .divider like this `.divider + .block + .block + .block + .block`

It works, however, I'd have to write the same for the 8th, 12th, 16th, .. block, which doesn't make it automatic anymore.

Is there something like `.divider + .block:nth-sibling(4)` or `.divider + .block:nth-of-class(4)`?

Maybe one of you got an idea on how to solve this without changing the source code or using javascript.

Comment: really dont feel like answering:
http://nthmaster.com/

the selector you're looking for is
:nth-of-type()

so
div.block:nth-of-type(2)

would select the 2nd div with class block and NOT
the first div with class = block

#goodluck #ytjukutja

Comment: apologies for the previous post, a lack of understanding. I did give it another try once i fully understood the Q but it seems @BoltClock is right, js seems to be your only option

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Such a pseudo-class would not work because you are expecting it to match elements relative to a different compound selector, which is not how simple selectors work. For example, if you wrote a complex selector that only had a single compound selector with that pseudo-class (and no sibling combinators):

```
.block:nth-sibling(4n)
```

Would you expect this to match `.block:nth-child(4n)`, match nothing at all, or be invalid?

It'd be nice to be able to abridge `+ .block + .block + .block + .block` and make it repeat somehow, but unfortunately due to how the selector syntax is designed, it's just not possible.

You'll have to use JavaScript and/or add extra classes to the appropriate elements instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's unfortunate but I sortof expected that there is no good solution without Javascript. Hopefully, the upcoming CSS selectors won't take too long to implement and be usable, until then, Javascript is the way to go.

Comment: Would something like `.divider +(4n) .block` be thinkable as a shortcut for `.divider + * + * + * + .block`, `.divider + * + * + * + * + * + * + * + .block` and so on? More generally, how are things looking 4 years later?

Comment: @overactor: I don't speak for the CSSWG - you might get better answers on www-style@w3.org.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that `:nth-of-type` refers to ***the type of element*** and both `.divider` and `.block` are elements of type `<div>`.

What you really need is for `.divider` to be a different type of element from `.block`.

---

On that basis, if the only two child elements of `<div class="wrap">` are:

1. `<div class="divider">`
2. `<div class="block">`

I'd be tempted to swap out `<div class="divider">` for `<hr>` - the *thematic break* element.

Then you *can* use:

```
 .wrap div:nth-of-type(4)
```

to style `.block`.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by BoltClock, you can't do this without JavaScript. If you choose that route (even though you explicitly say *without* JavaScript), it can be done with jQuery like this:

```
var counter = 0;
$('.wrap > div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('divider')) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('block')) {
        counter++;
        if (counter % 8 == 4) {
            $(this).css('background-color','#ff0');
        }
    }
});
```

That will color the 4th column in every row yellow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, kba. As you already pointed out, I was looking for a non-JS solution, besids my dirty CSS-way I also wrote a script similar to yours, both work fine, so thanks

Comment: you can do this without js

Comment: @CraigWayne Nobody in this question has managed to do so, so it's rather obnoxious to downvote and just state that it's possible without showing how.

Comment: @kba comment on OP, im anything but obnoxious. but to each their own. sorry man, i dont mean to criticise you, but it really can be without js... :nth-of-type()

Comment: @CraigWayne `nth-of-type()` will not work. Reread the question. He doesn't just want the _n_ th of a certain class, he wants the _n_ th of a certain class _after_ another class has appeared. Just selecting say the 4th div with class `block` is not what he's looking for. The answer you provided in the comment does not fulfill his requirement.

Comment: @kba apologies, It seems that I was a bit hasty, gave it a try again once I fully understood the Q, and it seems as though you are right, a css solution doesnt seem to work. once again, apologies for the criticism