# Is there a CSS selector for continuous siblings

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list as this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li class="class1">Important</li>
  <li>I want this</li>
  <li>I want this</li>
  <li class="class1">Important</li>
  <li>I want this</li>
  <li>I want this</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a CSS selector for the fist two `<li>` after each `.class1` element?

Comment: nth-of-type may be what you are looking for

Comment: Try reviewing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790256/css-something-like-nth-sibling)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.class1 + li` will select the first subsequent sibling.
`.class1 + * + li` will select the second.

to keep specificity low, you could also use:

```
.class1 + *,
.class1 + * + * {...}
```

but that's with the understanding that `.class1` only ever selects the appropriate `li` elements.

---

Both of these are fragile selectors. Fragile in that they will break when you change the markup even a little. Consider just adding more classes to target the appropriate elements, and keep your specificity low.

Comment: The second selector reference is actually pretty neat.

Comment: yeah never seen that before, pretty interesting

Comment: @Martin, then the [lobotomized owl selector](http://alistapart.com/article/axiomatic-css-and-lobotomized-owls) may very well blow your mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot, amazing trick. Unfortunately I have not the option to insert more classes for reference, that's why I needed this fragile - as you noted - solution

Comment: Wouldn't `.class1 + li, .class1 + li + li { color: red; }` have better performance than using `*`?

Comment: @Aziz, I've never been in a situation where CSS selector performance mattered. I would hazard a guess that anyone running into selector performance problems has a bigger problem to solve (too many elements on the page).

Comment: @zzzzBov haha, ASCII art and CSS function in some horrific combination. Thanks for the read.

Comment: "Both of these are fragile selectors. Fragile in that they will break when you change the markup even a little." Isn't that kind of the point? The OP *only* wants to target the two li elements that immediately follow each li with that class. There is no point bloating the markup by adding classes to each of the following two elements just to be able to target them *if they will only ever appear in that context anyway* - if you assigned those classes out of order, then the class selectors you propose would match incorrectly, and *that's* what I would call fragile.

Comment: @BoltClock, CSS is a declarative language, and as such it's beneficial to avoid attempting to describe deep relational paths when you can just use names. When I need my wife's father's brother's son's daughter to pass the potatoes, I just ask her by name. Going back to the issues of fragility here, if someone later removes a `<li>` such that the structure is `.class1 + li + .class1` you will have an unintended behavior. These changes are quite common, and complex relational selectors make changes hard because the intent is obscured.

Comment: @BoltClock, I should also note that it's quite likely that OP is using poorly structured markup, where a `dl>dt+dd` group or nested `ul` might be more appropriate. Without seeing a concrete example, I hesitate to suggest either option.